# Display more information about nodes

Tags: lists, graphs

I have a visual graph that represents connections between nodes. Users can find the connection between two nodes by typing names of both ends, which then provides all possible paths from start node to end node like this:

[image]

I want to find a way to display information such as Parents, Children etc. in a pleasant way. How can I rearrange or change this to be more suitable and comprehensible for users?

Each option in a tree has an action associated with it, for example: clicking Children -> V2 will take them to that node in a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to make it interactive, as user clicks on a node, highlight all children nodes with a common colour and show links with dotted lines. At the same time, show parent with some other colour and make current node-to-parent link as bold one. Unless user clicks on some other node, keep this colour coding intact. 
For information in menu, you can popup a menu like we get in Microsoft word when we select text. In that menu, show all children node links to right and parent node link to left for easy identification

Comment: I like this idea and in combination with @PiotrŻak I could have a right pane that shows more information about nodes. I would have to "isolate" related nodes by hiding the rest, because these graphs can get very complicated with tens of thousands of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

It's all depends on the specification and construction of the node

Nodes can have very complex and comprehensive structure.

Did you hear about Redux Devtools?

I think that in this tool connotations and connections between nodes  are readable, intuitive and work well.
I recommend to see how the module behaves during the interaction:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd

[image]

This structure helps understand the system & notice the data flow and define the path in a specific scenario.

---

Also, another solution, however, I have not encountered any practical use of it:
[image]